# How to handle Contentful content data in Gatsby

Tags: contentful, gatsby, netlify

I'm interested in using [Gatsby](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby) to build a [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com) static site using content from [Contentful](https://www.contentful.com/features/)

Netlify has this nice gettting started Gatsby guide:
​​https://www.netlify.com/blog/2016/02/24/a-step-by-step-guide-gatsby-on-netlify

But I'm a bit unsure of how to bring Contentful into the mix. Do I need to write scripts to convert my Contentful content into Gatsby 'markdown'?

Any ideas, ideas, links appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since this question was posted, an official Contentful plugin's been added to Gatsby's collection (official as in created by Gatsby team, not Contentful): https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/packages/gatsby-source-contentful

An example site's src code is here: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/examples/using-contentful

The plugin processes markdown via `gatsby-transformer-remark` and produces the resultant HTML, which you can access via Gatsby's GraphQL server w/ a query like this one from [the example proj](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/examples/using-contentful/src/templates/product.js):

```
 contentfulProduct(id: { eq: $id }) {
      productName {
        productName
      }
      productDescription {
        childMarkdownRemark {
          html
        }
      }
      price
    }
```

You can use the plugin to connect both to the Content API (for published assets/content) and/or the Preview API (for both published *and* draft content/assets).

We use `NODE_ENV` to pull from the Preview API in dev and the Content API in production.

Comment: Hi, What will the query format if I have to get data for 2 ids(or more). Is there anything like "in". Please help.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the script I am using to pull down data from Contentful:
https://gist.github.com/ivanoats/e79ebbd711831be2536d1650890055c4

I run this via an npm run script before gatsby build.

I would love to work on a plugin or get ideas on better architecture for this process.

I wrote a post on this architecture in more detail on the [Aerobatic blog](https://www.aerobatic.com/blog/a-serverless-cms-architecture)

Answer (score 0):

Right now the best option is to write a script which syncs content from Contentful to your Gatsby site's pages directory.

There's plans however for adding support within Gatsby to make this happen semi-automatically. Early days still here! See this issue for more https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/324

Comment: I like the idea of a webpack loader for contentful.