# Convert Markdown to HTML from within a Rich-Text Component with Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, markdown, gatsby, contentful

I am using Contentful's Rich-Text Field type to build pages, one of the Embedded_Blocks I have is for a Markdown field type which I am using to build a table:

Markdown Field Type:

```
| Title | Title | 
| ---------- | ---------- | 
| Cell | Cell |
```

I can retrieve the Rich-Text data and build out my Embedded_Blocks like this:

```
[BLOCKS.EMBEDDED_ENTRY]: (node) => {
   const fields = node.data.target.fields;
   switch (node.data.target.sys.contentType.sys.id) {
      case 'video':
          const url = (fields.url['en-US']);
          return <Video url={url}/>

      // This is how I'm currently trying to convert Markdown to HTML
      ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      case 'markdown':
          const markdown = (fields.markdown['en-US']);
          console.log('markdown', markdown);
          return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: markdown }} />
      default:
          return <div>Fallback</div>
   }
},
```

The problem I have with this is that it just returns a string, I'm assuming because I have not converted `markdown` to HTML before passing it to `dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: markdown }}`.

How can I convent the Markdown to HTML so that I can render it using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: markdown }}`?

Comment: what exactly is returning a string? and why is that a problem? `markdown` is supposed to be a string in `dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: markdown }}`

Comment: My understanding is that `dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: markdown }}` requires the the Markdown text has already been converted to a string containing HTML. This is not what I have. 
`const markdown = (fields.markdown['en-US']);` simply gives me a string of markdown that is unconverted. So `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` just displays the sting of markdown text as there is no HTML.

Comment: then you need to convert it to html first using e.g. markdown-it or https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-transformer-remark/

Comment: see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47113387/214446

Comment: @mb21 not sure the D'uh is deserved. My question clearly says that the converting to HTML is what I am having trouble with and it's clearly obvious that I know what dangerouslySetInnerHTML is for. I was asking for help not a smart attitude. Please read the question carefully in future before implying stupidity.

Answer (score 1):

The most appropriate way to do this inside of Gatsby would be to create child nodes inside of the Gatsby [`onCreateNode`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/node-apis/#onCreateNode) lifecycle hook.  This hook is only called in the nodejs process, and runs the markdown parsing once when the Contentful entry is downloaded.

This should get you started - it's based on the code inside of Gatsby's [`gatsby-transformer-remark`](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/packages/gatsby-transformer-remark/src/on-node-create.js#L4)

Note that this is pseudocode - you'll have to of course test it.

```js
// gatsby-node.js

var remark = require('remark')
var recommended = require('remark-preset-lint-recommended')
var html = require('remark-html')

const processor = remark()
  .use(recommended)
  .use(html)

export async function onCreateNode({ actions, node, loadNodeContent}) {
  if (!/RichText/.test(node.internal.type)) {
    return
  }

  const markdown = // somehow load the raw markdown from the node - I haven't studied RichText nodes yet

  const html = processor.process(markdown)

  const markdownNode = {
    id: createNodeId(`${node.id} >>> MarkdownRemark`),
    children: [],
    parent: node.id,
    internal: {
      content: data.content,
      type: `MarkdownRemark`,
    },
  }

  actions.createNode(markdownNode)
  actions.createParentChildLink({ parent: node, child: markdownNode })
}
```

For reference, [here is where Contentful creates the Rich Text nodes inside Gatsby:](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/packages/gatsby-source-contentful/src/normalize.js#L196)

Answer (score 1):

I implemented the solution using the package react-markdown

```
npm i react-markdown 
//using version "^5.0.2",
```

From your problem, I can see you are able to get the markdown content as a String. Use the package above parse the markdown content like so:

```
import ReactMarkdownWithHtml from "react-markdown/with-html";
```

replace:

```
return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: markdown }} />
```

with:

```
return <ReactMarkdownWithHtml children={markdown} allowDangerousHtml />
```

Here's their github page
[react-markdown](https://github.com/remarkjs/react-markdown)

You can use this package or any other React package that parses markdown inside Gatsby to parse your markdown strings.

Answer (score 0):

Using "micromark" worked for me...

1. I just added the dependency in package.json
2. In the gatsby.config.js I added the package:

   const micromark = require('micromark');
3. I used it to transform the node:

   {
   resolve: '@contentful/gatsby-transformer-contentful-richtext',
   options: {
   renderOptions: {
   renderNode: {

   ```
            [BLOCKS.EMBEDDED_ENTRY]:
              (node) => {
                const LANG = 'en-US';
                const ENTRY_TYPES = {
                  BUTTON: 'elementbutton',
                  TIP: 'elementtip',
                  QUOTE: 'elementquote',
                  IMAGE_COLUMN: 'elementimagecolumn',
                };
                const type = node.data.target.sys.contentType.sys.id;
                const { fields } = node.data.target;

                switch (type) {
                  case ENTRY_TYPES.QUOTE: {
                    const text = fields.text[LANG];
                    return `
                      <div class="${ENTRY_TYPES.QUOTE}">
                        ${micromark(text)}
                      </div>
                    `;
                  }
                  default:
                    return '';
                }
              },
          },
        },
      },
    },
   ```

Comment: Micromark v1+ is ESM-only, meaning you won't be able to import it into gatsby-node.js.