# How to use createResovers to convert a Markdown FIELD (not a file) to HTML in Gatsby

Tags: graphql, gatsby, airtable

The standard process for converting MD to HTML in Gatsby is for complete files on the local system.

I need to convert a specific field, NOT a file. The top related question is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55998067/convert-markdown-to-html-from-within-a-rich-text-component-with-gatsby), but as you can see that is using Contentful, which now provides a plugin to solve it.

The API I am using (Airtable) is returning a field that contains Markdown.

The [recommended solution](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/20162#issuecomment-567416249) is to convert using a resolver...but I cannot fully understand the Gatsby [docs on the topic](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/node-apis/#createResolvers).

The error I see when building is this:

```
UNHANDLED REJECTION Airtable.FAQ provided incorrect OutputType:
 'Object({ resolve: [function resolve], extensions: Object({ createdFrom: "createResolvers" }) })'
```

I think I am close, but I don't know if I am meant to create a new type or actually what the resolver is meant to return...a new field?

The field in question is `FAQ`, which you can see in this example of a query in the GraphQL explorer:

```json
query MyQuery {
  allAirtableManufacturer(filter: {data: {Premium: {eq: true}}}) {
    edges {
      node {
        data {
          Premium
          Manufacturer
          Premium_Manufacturers {
            recordId
            data {
              FAQ
              Downloads_File_Name
              Is_Supplier
            }
            internal {
              type
            }
          }
        }
        recordId
        queryName
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My understanding is that the resolver can/should add a new field with the markdown content converted to html.

So here is my resolver code, where you can see I am trying to add a field called "FAQ_html" to the Airtable node:

```
  createResolvers({
    Airtable: {
      FAQ_html: {
        resolve(source: any, args: any, context: any, info: any) {
          return remark().use(html).processSync(source.data.FAQ).contents
        },
      },
    }
  })
```

My gatsby-config for airtable is:

```
    resolve: `gatsby-source-airtable`,
      options: {
        apiKey: process.env.AIRTABLE_API_KEY,
        concurrency: 5,
        tables: [
          {
            baseId: `appP5vBdAitw6yyDH`,
            tableName: `Manufacturers`,
            queryName: `Manufacturer`,
            tableView: `AppView_Details_DONOTCHANGE`,
            tableLinks: [`Premium_Manufacturers`],
            separateNodeType: true,
            defaultValues: {
              Company_Description: '',
            },
          },
          {
            baseId: `appP5vBdAitw6yyDH`,
            tableName: 'Premium_Manufacturers',
            tableLinks: [`Manufacturers`],
          },

        ],
```

The table 'Premium_Manufacturers' is obviously linked as a child to 'Manufacturers'.

However, when I explore in GraphQL I also see them appear as a top-level node called 'Airtable', which I did not expect. You can see that here:

```
allAirtable {
    edges {
      node {
        data {
          FAQ
          Downloads_File_Name
          Last_update
          Is_Supplier
          Section_Name
          Section_No
          Name
          Cell_Number
          Email
          Rep_Name
          Technical_Rep_Name
          Consolidated_Rep
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

That's why my resolver uses 'Airtable' as the name of the node, but clearly it does not work.

I also tried changing the config to provide a separate node:

```
          {
            baseId: `appP5vBdAitw6yyDH`,
            tableName: 'Premium_Manufacturers',
            queryName: 'Premium',
            separateNodeType: true,
            tableLinks: [`Manufacturers`],
          },
```

so now 'allAirtable' becomes 'allAirtablePremium'.

I tried changing the resolver to use that:

```
  createResolvers({
    allAirtablePremium: {
      FAQ_html: {
        resolve(source: any, args: any, context: any, info: any) {
          return remark().use(html).processSync(source.data.FAQ).contents
        },
      },
    }
  })
```

But that throws a warning:

```
warn `createResolvers` passed resolvers for type `allAirtablePremium` that doesn't exist in the schema.
```

So clearly it doesn't like the 'all', so then I changed it to remove the 'all' like so:

```
  createResolvers({
    AirtablePremium: {
      FAQ_html: {
        resolve(source: any, args: any, context: any, info: any) {
          return remark().use(html).processSync(source.data.FAQ).contents
        },
      },
    }
  })
```

And I am back to the original error, which at least tells me there is something wrong with what I am trying to return (as the error clearly says 'wrong OutputType').

So what should that be returning?

Thanks in advance for any help!

**UPDATE 1**

The code now compiles, but I don't see my custom field.

This is the schema customisation (just create FAQ_HTML as an empty string to start off):

```
import { GatsbyNode, CreateSchemaCustomizationArgs } from 'gatsby'

export const createSchemaCustomization: GatsbyNode['createSchemaCustomization'] = async ({
  actions,
}: CreateSchemaCustomizationArgs) => {

  const { createFieldExtension, createTypes } = actions
  createFieldExtension({
    name: "FAQ_HTML",
    extend() {
      return ''
    },
  })

  const typeDefs = `
    type airtablePremium implements Node {
      FAQ_HTML: String @FAQ_HTML
    }
`

  createTypes(typeDefs)
}
```

The resolver is now like this:

```
  createResolvers({
    airtablePremium: {
      FAQ_HTML: {
        resolve(source: any, args: any, context: any, info: any) {
          console.log("SOURCE IS", source)
          const faqHtml = remark().use(html).processSync(source.FAQ).contents
          console.log("faqHtml IS", faqHtml)
          return faqHtml;
        },
      },
    },
  })
```

It compiles but the field does not show up in the GraphQL explorer. No console output either.

Comment: The error message is for `Airtable.FAQ` though the listed output type looks like it belongs to your `FAQ_html` field, so maybe Gatsby is confused there. Try declaring your `FAQ_html` field in onSchemaCustomization `createTypes` first.

Also it looks like in the resolver it should be `source.FAQ`, not `source.data.FAQ`. You can add console.log in the body of the resolve function and then try to query the data in graphiQL to see if the process log anything.

Comment: @DerekNguyen Thanks, some great pointers there. Getting closer...! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a nice chat with @rmcsharry, we confirmed that you'd need to create the type first.

```js
createTypes(`
  type AirtablePremium implements Node @infer {
    FAQ_HTML: String
  }
`)
```

The biggest issue was the *type name*. In the code, it should be `AirtablePremium` vs `airtablePremium`. You can find out the type name in GraphiQL by clicking on the field name in the left column, or holding <kbd>cmd</kbd> and clicking on the field in your query.

You'd use the typename in `createResolvers` as well:

```js
  createResolvers({
    AirtablePremium: {
      FAQ_HTML: {
        resolve(source: any, args: any, context: any, info: any) {
          ...
        },
      },
    },
  })
```

**Update from @rmcsharry**

After @Derek Nguyen's very helpful assistance, I found an alternative and easier solution.

If you want to avoid the hassle of creating types, you can go with a much simpler solution using the plugin [markdown-to-jsx](https://github.com/probablyup/markdown-to-jsx).

Then you simply wrap the incoming markdown field:

```
<Markdown>{field}</Markdown>
```

and it creates a react JSX component on the fly. :)